# Limit of partial sums of a sequence

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to determine if the following limit exists: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n-1})^\alpha$$  
Where alpha is some real number (The answer might depend on the choice of alpha). 
This is the only question in my homework I was not able to do, I tried to define $a_n=(\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n-1})^\alpha$ and look if something interesting happens with $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ or with $\sum2^n \cdot a_{2^n}$ but unfortunately it did not work. Thank you for your help, and if you answer me please try to make your answer as basic as possible, because I'm not advanced yet so I don't know much (it should be basic, as this is a homework question at calculus 1 course). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The key issue here is that you need to exploit some sort of **cancellation** between the two halves of the summands; the trivial estimate that the summands are just about bounded by $(2n^{1/3})^{\alpha}$ when $\alpha > 0$ isn't good enough.

A standard trick to study these is to use the binomial theorem to give a sharp approximation of the power function. To wit,

$$(n + 1)^{1/3} = n^{1/3}\left(1 + \frac 1 n\right)^{1/3} = n^{1/3} \left(1 + \frac 1 3 \frac 1 n + O(n^{-2})\right) \approx n^{1/3} + \frac 1 3 n^{-2/3}$$

Using a similar approximation for the other half of the summand, the question you really need to answer is for which $\alpha$ the series

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left(n^{-2/3}\right)^{\alpha}$$

converges.

Comment: That's a great answer! It's totally beside the point, but I need to ask: what does "to wite" mean?

Comment: @rafa11111 Thanks! It was a typo of [to wit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20wit), a slightly archaic way to say "namely."

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! can you just explain to me what does that O(n^-2) mean? never saw it before. thanks!

Comment: @Omer It's "big O notation," and it just means that there is an error term which is no larger than (a multiple of) $n^{-2},$ which is negligible in this context.

Comment: That's really a too complicated method for an asker that is asking for "please try to make your answer as basic as possible, because I'm not advanced yet so I don't know much". You should read carefully the OP before to answer to it. Refer to my answer based only on algebraic methods.

Comment: Moreover the explanation given in the comments for the meaning of Big-O notation is really misleading and absolutely not rigorous, givin the false impression that we can handle that without the necessary caution.

Comment: @gimusi If you had ever taught a calculus course, you might know that the binomial series and similar approximations are frequently among topics covered in the sequence/series chapter of many books... not that that's actually relevant, because literally all I'm using is that $(1 + x)^{\beta} \approx. 1 + \beta x$ follows from differentiating at zero. I know that the motive of your vote is because you're a bit salty about some of your own answers getting downvoted, so it doesn't really bug me. Please go bother someone else.

Comment: I'm just applying your same method of evaluation used for other answers, I don't know what kind of calculus courses you taught but the concept you have used here are uselessly advanced to solve that simple problem which requires just an algebraic approach. That's my point of view on that.

Comment: @gimusi Cool beans.

Answer (score 1):

As a simpler method recall that

$$A^3-B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2) \implies A-B=\frac{A^3-B^3}{A^2+AB+B^2}$$

then

$$\sqrt[3]{n+1}-\sqrt[3]{n-1}=\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^2}+\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}+\sqrt[3]{(n-1)^2}} \sim\frac2{3n^\frac23}$$

then the given series converges by [**limit comparison test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum \left(\frac1{n^{2/3}}\right)^\alpha$ for $\frac23\alpha >1$ that is $\alpha>\frac32$.